# Typescript alias with dot

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, openlayers-6

I have following imports (in the same TS source file):

```
import {Vector as sourceVector} from "ol/source";
import {Vector} from "ol/layer";
```

Here is how **Vector** is exported in *ol/source*:

```
export { default as Vector } from './source/Vector';
```

And *ol/layer*:

```
export { default as Vector } from './layer/Vector';
```

Is it possible to refactor imports somehow so it will look like this:

```
import {Vector as source.Vector} from "ol/source";
import {Vector as layer.Vector} from "ol/layer";
```

Unfortunately I don't have any control over *ol/source* and *ol/layer* and I can't affect their design decisions and naming conventions. I have to import and use both types in the same source code:

```
  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    const markerSource = new sourceVector({});

    this.map = new Map({
      layers: [
        new TileLayer({
          source: new OSM(),
        }),
        new Vector({ source: markerSource }),
      ],
      view: new View({
        center: fromLonLat([11.57548, 48.137552]),
        zoom: 13,
      }),
      target: this.myMap.nativeElement,
    });
```

Comment: No `as source.Vector` is not valid syntax. And why is this better than `as sourceVector` ?

Comment: Why not do something like `import * as source from 'ol/source'` and then call `source.Vector`?

Comment: @cs95 this might break tree shaking (not sure if applicable here)

Comment: thanks lovely people, I will stick with SourceVector for now, and 'import * as source from 'ol/source'' is answer to my particular question. @cs95, can you please post it here as answer and mention side effects mentioned by Aleksey?

Comment: @AlekseyL. TIL, thanks for calling it out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your question:

```
import * as source from 'ol/source';
import * as layer from "ol/layer";
```

<sub>P.S.: Beware that this *could* possibly break [tree shaking](https://webpack.js.org/guides/tree-shaking/) (but I'm not quite sure how you'd verify that).</sub>

---

But as mentioned in the [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64630038/typescript-alias-with-dot?noredirect=1#comment114275553_64630038), this isn't necessarily better than what you're already doing:

```
import {Vector as sourceVector} from "ol/source";
import {Vector as layerVector} from "ol/layer";
```

You can safely refer to either without any naming clash and it's still pretty readable.